# Rotated text spills out of browser window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, transform, fluid-layout

I'm having problems with a rotated header inside a fluid-layout website : I'd like to have this header to adjust according to the height of the browser window. However, right now, when I'm resizing the window, the top of the text spills out and is hidden.

I figured out that it might have to do with the viewport and the new "mobile-first" approach of Bootstrap 3, but I'm really flying blind otherwise. Also, applying `overflow : hidden` property, without success.

Here's the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <header>
                <h1>Welcome to Yd Design</h1>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS :

```
@import "bootstrap.min.css";

html {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    -moz-transform-origin : 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin : 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin : 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin : 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;

    -moz-transform : rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform : rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform : rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform : rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5.6em;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Edit :

As requested, I added a JSFiddle. I also added the browser specific prefixes for compatibility.

http://jsfiddle.net/smpte11/v6s9H/

Comment: Could you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I added the JSFiddle as you asked. Thx in advance!

Comment: I think the only possibility is to check the width of the header with javascript and change its position accordingly. PLease prove me wrong, I hate that idea ;)

Comment: @user1950929, you could see my solution. Did I prove you wrong?

Comment: @redolent only half :D I was thinking about dynamic sizes, but I will try out your ideas. I had the same problem some while ago and used jQuery to fix it. didn't like that much ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. For the container that's rotated (in this case, `<header>`), set its *width* to a value, like 500px.
2. Then, set the parent container's *margin-top* to the same value (500px).

For a full example, I modified your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6s9H/3/

---

Extra notes:

For a dynamic width, it would take more work. I would suggest rotating the parent container and positioning it, then doing a *float:right* on the header with no set width on the header but instead on one of the parent containers. In short, you could do a dynamic width by experimenting with more nested div's.

Comment: Thx a lot! I will try experimenting with your dynamic solution as well. Thx again!